Eslint does not show me option -> To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style
I am learning to configure Eslint, when I put the npx eslint --init command, I noticed that it does not show me all the options as it appears in several tutorials, I have also noticed as I continue advancing that it omits other questions, I am using node v20.11.0 I've had the problem for 3 days now and I haven't been able to solve it. I leave the capture of all the configurations that it has allowed to be made.

I have verified that eslint is installed only in the project folder, I have uninstalled and reinstalled eslint, but I have not been able to solve it.
As you can see in the package.json I am using the latest version of Eslint v9.2.0

I was having the same problem until i installed the package below. Hope it works for you too.
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb

